# Do users with low rep get “close request” acted on quicker then high rep users?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, vote-to-close

I think I have seen an odd side effect of how the review systems work.

If a user without enough rep to close a question flags the question, then the people looking at the flag queue seem to close the question very quickly.

However if someone with enough rep votes to close the questions, it sits in a never ending queue.

Comment: I don't see that this is a problem. Also what would be the solution?

Comment: @MartinSmith, Well what if I started to flag posts, rather than voting to close them as it is more effective….

Comment: Sorry I don’t know a solution,

Comment: Any "solution" would involve either making flag requests slower (surely undesirable) or making normal VTC requests faster surely. It is within the capabilities of higher rep users to do something about the size of the close vote queue but many choose not to!

Comment: Treat flag-to-close the same as any other close vote, and add them to the same queue.  (It already does that, so all that is required is to not show them again to the flags queue.)

Comment: @KevinPanko - And how would that benefit anything? If reviewers are already happy tackling that small subset of close decisions but balk at tackling the larger queue they will just end up ignored along with the rest.

Comment: @MartinSmith it would make it more fair.  But maybe we want it to remain unfair?  Flags to close should get more attention than votes to close?  When a question is really bad, I should both vote to close and then also flag it so it gets closed really fast.  I would even get more "helpful" flags which earns me badges and hats!  Hmm, yes.

Comment: @KevinPanko - Well as a high rep user on SO that rarely attempts the close vote queue I accept that I can't really grumble about how long it takes for my own votes to be processed. So in some respects it is more fair to treat lower rep users flags with priority as they *can't* do anything about it. I just choose not to.